# javascript insert into form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to send data via javascript through a form, however it's not working. any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="test.php">
<input id="myvar" type="hidden" name="albumid" />

<button type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(){     
    var album = '11';
    document.getElementById('myvar').value = album;

  });
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $_GET["albumid"]; ?>
```

Comment: try this instead: `document.getElementById('myvar').setAttribute('value',album);`

Comment: Your code is right. It's working on my side.

Comment: wrap the function around `$(document).ready(function(){....});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. You're missing `http:` in `src` when loading jquery library
2. Since you loading jquery use it `$('#myvar').val(album);`. See more on [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

That being said try

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <input id="myvar" type="hidden" name="albumid" />
    <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function() {     
        var album = '11';
        $('#myvar').val(album);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop default action on submit event:

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var album = '11';
    $('#myvar').val(album);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` to form and submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="get" action="test.php">
<input id="myvar" type="hidden" name="albumid" />

<button type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(){     
    var album = '11';
    document.getElementById('myvar').value = album;
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();

  });
</script>
```